# Where to place page specific CSS?

Tags: html, css

If I have a set of rules specific to a particular page, where should I place the CSS code?

- page level
- in a separate CSS file specific to page (separate file for each page where required)
- or all CSS code in a common file

What is the most efficient method?

Comment: This question isn't making any sense to me.

Comment: Are you talking about giving the general wrapper a special class per each page and adding selectors to the whole page according to this class?

Comment: Do you mean 'Is it bad practice to put the CSS inline on the page instead of in a .css file'?

Comment: @SeanJohnson Updated the question, please check...

Comment: Unless your pages are *vastly* different, adding a handful of page-specific rules to your main stylesheet isn't going to hurt any. Your users will essentially 'pay' for extra few bytes up front, but save when they actually visit that page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Say for example if you have an element having a class which is only on that single page, and no where in the website, say *maintenance page* and you've a bunch of styles which you do not want to include in the main CSS file as it is only applicable for that page, including those styles in the core stylesheet doesn't make any sense, as it will bloat your stylesheet by few bytes or kbs.. so you might use document level styles in this case, this will minify your core CSS file, so this is for `performance/optimization`

On the other hand you might also use document level styles when it comes to priority as *document level styles* have *greater priority* compared to external CSS.

What's the bad part is these styles *aren't cached*, so some developers also use document level style declarations say for some core places thus preventing pages to apply cached styles(this is another good part as styles aren't cached, so it's kinda two-faced).

---

As you edited your question, the best way to go for page specific styles is to include the block of `<style>` tag in the `<head>` of that document(not a compulsion though) and do not include these styles in your core/general stylesheet.

- Page Level - **YES**
- In a separate CSS file specific to page (separate file for each page where required) - **NO**

  *this will increase number of stylesheets, and also it will lead to an additional `http` request*
- Or all CSS code in a common file - **NO**, *this will bloat your core stylesheet unnecessarily.*